# How to pass id with url to php file using ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to pass id with ajax to a php file. I tried a lot but couldnot succed. I want to return to the page with id. Please help me.

I tried like this.

```
 <script>

      jQuery.ajax({
                var registration_date=$("#registration_date").val()                    
               var building_length_ft=$("#building_length_ft").val();
                var building_length_in=$("#building_length_in").val();
                var building_breadth_ft=$("#building_breadth_ft").val();
                 var reg_id=$_GET['id'].val();
                 var dataString = $('#a').serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'registration_detail.php',
                    method:'POST',
                   data: dataString,
                   success:function(data){
                       alert(data);
                   }
                });
            });

    </script>
```

I tried below code as well.

```
    var reg_id=$_GET['id'].val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'registration_detail.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                   'reg_id=' + reg_id,
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                       alert(data);
                   }
                });
```

```
I tried below code as well.
var id = $('#id').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'registration_detail.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data: { id: id},
                   success: function(response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
                });
```

Comment: You can't mix php and javascript that way. Php runs only on server...not in browser. Read up on how to access url query params using javascript

Comment: I tried other methods as well but couldnot solve. Please help me.@charlietfl

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams

Comment: I'm able to get id but couldn't pass to php file.  I want to pass id through url in ajax call and return to the php file with id . eg:http://localhost/bps/registration_detail.php?id=62. I tried a lot.@charlietfl

Comment: JUst concatenate it to the string url `url:'registration_detail.php?id=' +id,`

Comment: It doesnot work.@charlietfl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your code:

```
<script>

      jQuery.ajax({
                var registration_date=$("#registration_date").val()                    
               var building_length_ft=$("#building_length_ft").val();
                var building_length_in=$("#building_length_in").val();
                var building_breadth_ft=$("#building_breadth_ft").val();
                // There is a PHP script here:
                 var reg_id=<?= $_GET['id'] ?>;
                 var dataString = $('#a').serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'registration_detail.php',
                    method:'POST',
                   data: dataString,
                   success:function(data){
                       alert(data);
                   }
                });
            });

    </script>
```

Comment: I tried but couldnot get id  in php file@Julyano Felipe. Please help me.I'm so frusted